# Executable working in solaris but not in linux

Tags: linux, solaris, executable

I have an executable in Solaris which when i migrate to linux doesn't work.

> bash: ./client: cannot execute binary file

I came through some points that I need to recompile the code in linux to make it work, but the issue is I have only executable and no source code.
I wanted to decompile the code from executable in solaris, but couldn't find any decompiler in the environment

Can anyone suggest a way out. I am stuck here.
Help much appreciated.

Comment: See if this helps your cause : http://superuser.com/questions/435988/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-cannot-execute-binary-file

Comment: Didn't help :(...All i can make out is the executable was copied from Solaris to Linux, so some compatibility error.

Comment: "Compatibility error" indeed.  Solaris and Linux are different operating systems.  An executable built to run on Solaris simply isn't going to run on Linux.  Even if the underlying hardware is the same, and it may very well not be.  What's the output from `file /path/to/your/executable`, on both Linux and Solaris?

Comment: If you were trying this the other way round it would succeed. This is because Solaris x86 has a Linux system call shim and a loader to suit (or certainly used to). It's basically the same idea as Bash on Windows 10, BB10's support for Android, and I think FreeBSD also has a Linux system call shim. OS authors add shims like this when they think the other guy's software is more popular than their own OS environment. In theory Linux could be given a Solaris shim, but no one can see any value in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for running a Solaris binary on Linux. Given the fact it seems the binary if for x86, your best option is to run it on a VM. Solaris is well supported on VirtualBox.